# Loop through object key/values correctly for active body class

Tags: javascript, jquery, key-value, for-in-loop

I'm trying to loop through an object with some data in it, compare the value to the window width, find out which one is essentially 'active' in the range, then use that in the body tag.

```
var breakpoints = {'size-s': 320, 'size-m': 768, 'size-l': 1024, 'size-xl': 1440},
    activeClass;

$(window).on('resize orientationchange', function () {
    for (var prop in breakpoints) {
        if($(window).width() > breakpoints[prop] && $(window).width() < breakpoints[prop]) {
            activeClass = prop;
        }
    }
});
```

**Examples:**

- If window width = 800 that means that the activeClass should be 'size-m'.
- If window width = 1023 that means that the activeClass should be 'size-m'.
- If window width = 1024 that means that the activeClass should be 'size-l'.

Fairly sure this is the direction but don't understand the premise(s) in order to progress. A little help would be great :)

NOTE: Well aware of css media queries - has to be a js solution please :)

Comment: Why not just use a responsive stylesheet? A whole lot less complicated and more reliable

Comment: This literally cannot be both true `if($(window).width() > breakpoints[prop] && $(window).width() < breakpoints[prop])`

Comment: You can also use the [`.matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) function.

Comment: You should use `$(window).width() == breakpoints[prop]` in place of `$(window).width() > breakpoints[prop] && $(window).width() < breakpoints[prop]` if you want to check for equality

Comment: @AniketSahrawat thats going to be as bad if not worse. Not everyone uses fully maximized browser windows

Comment: I thought this `$(window).width() > breakpoints[prop] && $(window).width() < breakpoints[prop]` was to check for equality.

Comment: @Harry L - I suspect what you're trying to do is a solved problem. Check out [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: @Jamiec well aware of media queries, ta. Need a js solution :)

Comment: So when you say `compare the value to the window width` what does that mean exactly? Clearly not everybody will have a browser width which matches exactly your input. And as I stated above you have an obvious logical failure.

Comment: @Jamiec added some examples for you to show you what I mean. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, thats clearer, but can you change that `breakpoints` object, as its not going to be easy to form a range from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the logic of comparing same property as < and >

```
$(window).width() > breakpoints[prop] && $(window).width() < breakpoints[prop]
```

I have corrected it, also introduced a different logic.
Breakpoints can work like this

```
var breakpoints = {
 'size-s':  { 'size' : 320, 'next' : 'size-m'},
 'size-m': { 'size' : 768, 'next' : 'size-l'},
 'size-l': { 'size' : 1024, 'next' : 'size-xl'},
 'size-xl': { 'size' : 1440, 'next' : undefined}};
```

Now each break point has its higher screen size, like a a linked hash map. Watch out for the bottle necks.

The working fiddle is here https://jsfiddle.net/p7nh7eyn/

Comment: Nice one, Melvin! Great solution!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you could change your input object, I would instead make it look like this:

```
var breakpoints = {
     'size-s': { min:0, max: 320}, 
     'size-m': { min:320, max: 768}, 
     'size-l': { min:768, max: 1024}, 
     'size-xl': { min:1024, max: 1440}
};
```

Hopefully you see just how easy it makes the code

```
$(window).on('resize orientationchange', function () {
    for (var prop in breakpoints) {
        if($(window).width() > breakpoints[prop].min && $(window).width() <= breakpoints[prop].max) {
            activeClass = prop;
        }
    }
});
```